# Подсчет количества дней из даты

Tags: java, дата, calendar

У меня есть метод, который считает разницу между датой покупки и датой продажи. Мне нужно высчитать количество дней, которое прошло в этом промежутке.

сейчас есть такой код:

```
public int storeDays(GregorianCalendar dateOfPurchase, GregorianCalendar dateOfSale) {
        int storeDays=dateOfPurchase.get(Calendar.DATE)-dateOfSale.get(Calendar.DATE);

    }
```

Как из `storeDays`высчитать количество дней?
И вообще правильно ли я выполняю данную задачу? Или может мне будет проще изначально перевести даты в дни и от них отнимать?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3796841

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103064/java-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: старайтесь чекать stackoverflow.com зачем плодить дубли.

Comment: @diofloyk, нет ничего плохого в дубликатах ;-) Более того, stackoverflow.com - не совсем тоже самое, что и **ru.**stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал `Joda Time`

```
public int storeDays(String dateOfPurchase, String dateOfSale) {
            this.dateOfPurchase = dateOfPurchase;
            this.dateOfSale = dateOfSale;
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy");
            int storeDays = 0;
        try {
            Date date1 = format.parse(dateOfPurchase);
            Date date2 = format.parse(dateOfSale);

            DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date1);
            DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(date2);

            storeDays = Days.daysBetween(dt1, dt2).getDays();

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return storeDays;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```
int storeDays=(int) ((dateOfPurchase.getTimeInMillis()-dateOfSale.getTimeInMillis())/1000/60/60/24);
```

Comment: Жаль, в вашем ответе нету пояснений - это не есть хорошо. К тому же, подход с делением на какое-то магическое число - не самый лучший вариант. В некоторых сутках бывает не по 24 часа.

Comment: @mymedia А как вы бы сделали?

Comment: Полагаю, стоит использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку для работы со временем. Например, [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff).

Comment: @mymedia Большое спасибо, именно то что я искал!